Does Blazor have an LSP for modal text editors like vim and helix?
I can't find an LSP for Blazor for ASP.net which I need to use in an editor like vim or helix.
I tried looking at the documentation and Stack Overflow: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/tooling?view=aspnetcore-8.0&pivots=vsc. There is tooling for VS Code and Visual Studio, but I couldn't find an LSP anywhere.
